# Как изменить значение label из таблицы

Tags: swift, uitableview, label

Как во ViewController изменить значение label при помощи tableview выбирая ячейку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот класс

```
import UIKit

class CreateNoteViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    var tableData = ["One","Two","Three"]

    let labelSpecieText = "Specie"

  @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet weak var labelSpecie: UILabel!

    required init (coder aDecoder:(NSCoder!)){
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)!
    }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    labelSpecie.text = labelSpecieText

  }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{

        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"CellSpecie")

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(path!)
        labelSpecie.text = cell!.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

Comment: а почему просто не написать `labelSpecie.text = tableData[indexPath.row]` ?

Answer (score 1):

UPD Проверьте еще `outlets`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Предположим, что все у Вас работает правильно, просто не меняется сразу текст. Добавьте:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! UITableViewCell
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.labelSpecie.text = cell.textLabel!.text
    })    
}
```

Comment: а бывает такое, чтобы didselectrowatindexpath вызывался не на main thread?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko судя по множеству тем, бывает, либо это из-за чего-то другого. К примеру, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320591/uitableview-and-presentviewcontroller-takes-2-clicks-to-display . Еще, кстати, нужно узнать, а что с `delegate` у `UITableView`